# Ключевое слово new выделяет лишние элементы для массива. C++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

В *strcopy()* выполняется копирование. Массив чаров, который я хочу копировать не имеет лишних элементов, а тот массив в который я хочу копировать элементы создаётся с лишними. 
Вот скрины с отладкой и сам код.

```
static int strlen(char* str)
{
    int len = 0;
    for (len = 0; str[len]; (len)++);
    return len;
}
static char* strcopy(char* dest, const char* src) // копирую строки
{
    int count = strlen(src); // нахожу длину 
    delete[] dest;
    dest = new char[count]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        *(dest + i) = *(src + i);
    }

    return dest;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про нулевой символ забыли. А отладчик просто содержимое памяти показывает.

Comment: О каких "лишних" элементах идёт речь, если вы не указали, где заканчивается ваша строка? В "бесконечной" строке не бывает "лишних" элементов.

Comment: Во-первых, зачем очищать источник в функции копирования? Это ведь не перемещение. Во-вторых, какое значение принимает `count`? `count` показывает кол-во элементов с "лишними" или без?

Comment: @V-Mor Я очищал не источник, а дестинейшн(dest) и после его инициализировал массивом char. Переменная count нужна для определения длины массива.

Comment: А если вы случайно напишете `char dest[10]; strcopy(dest,"какая-то хрень");`? что получится? :) А вообще - то, что вас расстраивает - решается одной единичкой: `int count = strlen(src)+1;`...

Comment: Этот код не собирается, так как вызов `strlen` происходит с невалидным аргументом. Более того, переопределение стандартных функций является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: @VTT, они же у него в отдельном namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы в образовательных целях хотите написать свою реализацию функции [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy), то для начала нужно прочитать, как эта функция определена в стандарте:

> #### `std::strcpy`
>
> ```
> #include <cstring>
> char* strcpy( char* dest, const char* src );
> ```
>
> Копирует символы из строки, на которую указывает `src`, включая нуль-терминатор в массив символов, на первый элемент которого указывает `dest`.
>
> Поведение не определено, если размера `dest` недостаточно для копирования. Поведение не определено, если строки перекрываются.
>
> **Параметры**
>
> `dest` — указатель на массив символов для записи
>   `src` — указатель на нуль-терминированную строку для чтения

1. Обратите внимание на фразу «*включая нуль-терминатор*». Вы этого не учли:

   > ```
   > int count = strlen(src); // нахожу длину 
   > ...
   > for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
   > ```

   Решение — `count = strlen(src) + 1`.
2. Функция `strcpy` не должна освобождать память! Что если вы в качестве `dest` передадите массив не созданный с помощью `new`?
3. Размера `int` может не хватить для длины строки. Используйте `std::size_t`.
4. Чтобы не писать `*(dest + i)` был придуман синтаксический сахар — `dest[i]`.

Comment: Я удалял массив `dest` только для того, чтобы предотвратить утечку памяти. Просто если я переопределю указатель `dest` на другую область в памяти, то прошлая область сама себя не очистит ведь. Значит, если мне нельзя удалять прошлую область в памяти прямо в ф-ции, то как это тогда можно реализовать?

Comment: @zZEN, функция `strcpy` предполагает, что размера строки `dest` достаточно для копирования в нее `src`. Поэтому переопределять указатель `dest` ненужно. Если же размера не хватает, то тогда вам придется вручную увеличить размер памяти, выделенной под строку `dest` (функцией `realloc`, например), но делать это нужно **вне** функции `strcpy`. Для того чтобы бороться с таким неудобством зачастую пишут свои библиотеки, реализующие строки динамического размера. Одна из самых известных таких библиотек — [sds](https://github.com/antirez/sds).

Answer (score 2):

`strcopy` не должна ни выделять, ни очищать. В функциях очищать память передаваемых аргументов вообще нельзя. Например должен работать такой код (в начале строки хотите записать длину строки) :

```
const char* src = "hello"
size_t len = strlen(src) 
char* dst = new char[len+9];
*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(dst) = len;
strcopy(dst + 4, src);
```

И на `delete[] dest;` в strcopy у вас всё упадет. Когда вы пишете функцию, вы НЕ знаете как очищать память преданного аргумента. Выделять память в функции в принципе можно, но по возможности стоит избегать. Ибо тому, кто будет в вашем коде разбираться придется выяснять, а как её потом очищать. Желательно выделять и очищать на одном уровне абстракции.

Другой пример. Иногда используют свой аллокатор. Чтобы реже использовать медленный вызов new, выделяют через new большой кусок памяти(арену), а потом просят с этой арены выдать свободный кусок. Тогда ваш new в strcopy будет вообще не к месту, а delete вообще уронит программу.

Если посмотреть требования к функции strcpy, в ответе товарища @eanmos, то реализация в с++ должна быть какой-то такой.

```
static size_t strlen(char* str)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len] != 0) {
        ++len;
    } 
    return len;
}

static char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; ; ++i) {
        dest[i] = str[i];
        if (str[i] == 0) {
            return dest;
        } 
    }
}
```